# SQL: difference between INNER JOIN and INNER SELECT in particular case

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I start to learn SQL. And I find that we often can achieve the same result with help of JOINs or Inner Select statements.

**Question1 (broad):** Where JOINs are faster than inner selects and vise versa?

**Question2 (narrow):** Can you explain me what causes performance difference of three queries below?

**P.S.** There is [very nice site](http://sql-ex.com/perfcon.php) which calculates query performance, but I can't understand it estimation results.

**Query1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker 
FROM Product pro INNER JOIN Printer pri
on pro.model = pri.model
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker
FROM Product 
WHERE model IN (
  SELECT model FROM Printer
)
```

**Query3:**

```
SELECT distinct maker 
FROM Product pro, Printer pri 
WHERE pro.model = pri.model
```

Comment: It's more complicated than that. I was fortunate enough to start using (my)SQL just before subqueries came along. Subqueries can bring tremendous performance benefits, but I still think it's better, when learning, to try to construct queries without them.

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-query (query 2) is useless.

Answer (score 2):

When the server evaluate a JOIN it matches the join equivalence scanning only the columns needed only for the value in the other table, and filter out everything else, it is usually done with a specific action.
When you have a subquery the server need to evaluate the plan for the subquery before the JOIN equivalence match, so if the subquery doesn't make up for the extra effort filtering out a lot of noise you have a better perfomance without it.

The server are quite smart, and they try to shave everything they don't need to evaluate the join. Then they try to use every index they can to have the best performance, where the best performance mean the best they can find in a limited amount of time, so that the plan time itself  don't kill the performance.

**Added after the comment of the OP**
The O(n) estimation depent on the complexity of the query and the subquery, if you are interested on the query plan building you'll have to navigate the help section of your database of choice and probably you will not find a lot, if the DB is not opensource.
In layman term:

- a the simple join is evaluated on one level, the main query plan
- a sub query is evaluated on two level, the subquery plan and the main query plan.

Some DB IDE can display a visual rappresentation of the total plan, that usually help to understand some of those point (I don't know if mySQL has that)

Comment: thanks. But seems I still can't grasp it. Can you provide full disclosure with example and O(n) estimation please?

Answer (score 1):

Query1 is faster in general but RDBMC could optimize the Query2 to provide approximately the same result.

If the IN subquery rather complicated with dependencies from main table(s) it could be executed for each row retrieved to check the condition.

Comment: I thought that the second query is faster. Can you please explain with more details why join is faster please? It'll be greate if you'll tell me how does the joins work (I mean algorithm ).

Comment: it goes through the first table and for each row checks record with the joined id in the second table

Comment: so if I've got N rows in the first table and M rows in the second table, JOIN will make N*M comparisons? In the same moment inner select will make N + M iterations (M - to select model from Printer and N to select all products' makers).

Comment: No N*M comparisons. There are indexes

Comment: can you write iterations for each query please? I mean sequence of steps.

Answer (score 1):

Normally `INNER JOIN` is to join two different table values ,where as `INNER SELECT` is to select a particular value from a different table and use the result to produce a single output.

Comment: yes. But chiefly this question is about WHY it's in such way?